# Не могу передать данные от дочерних элементов

Tags: angular, rxjs

У меня есть следующая структура:

```
<angularComp1>

   <angularComp2>
      <a>Route to detail page</a>

      <angularComp3>
        <button>Edit </button>
      </angularComp3>

   </angularComp2>

</angularComp1>
```

Я передаю данные с компонента 1 в компонент 2, дальше через роут перехожу на нужную мне страницу(оказываюсь на компоненте 3), в 3 компоненте есть кнопка, по нажатию я изменяю входящие данные. Проблема состоит в том что я не знаю как передать изменение данные обратно в компонент 1 и уже там визвать нужный мне метод. Сначало думал сделать через емитер , но если таких компонентов будет 1000, то придеться делать 1000 емитеров, дальше думал написать сервис ( он б отслеживал данные и передавал, куда мне надо) , но тут у мня возникла проблема как из компонента 3 вызвать нужны мне метод в 1.

Comment: чувак, делай примеры на codesandbox или stackblitz. Так будет в 20х раз легче разобраться в твоей задаче, без примера приходится глубоко вдаваться в контекст. Например у меня сразу возникает вопрос как ты можешь передавать данные с компонента2 в компонент3 - если компонент3 это "роутинговый" компонент? В вопросе ты это не указал. Почему не хочешь использовать обычный сервис?

Comment: Как вариант посмотри в сторону NgRX [https://ngrx.io/docs](https://ngrx.io/docs)